# How to Post Long Data to Web API

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I am posting json string to Web Api in VB.NET windows application. This json data contains thousands or millions characters. When i posting data to web api , throwing error without explanation. I changed data to small data and posted successfully. So what is the best way posting long json data to web api ?

**EDIT**  windows application throwing error but after data came to web api method.

```
Using cl As New HttpClient()
    cl.BaseAddress = New Uri(proxyUrl)
    cl.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear()
    Dim j = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rest)
    response = cl.PostAsync("api/Restaurant", New StringContent(j.ToString, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result
    Dim Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of ResponseResult)(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result)
    If Data.Succeed Then
        Veri.Tools.Utils.VeriMsg("Güncelleme Başarılı", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Güncelleme Başarılı")
    Else
        Veri.Tools.Utils.VeriMsg("Güncelleme Tamamlanamadı", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Güncelleme Tamamlanamadı")
    End If
End Using
```

Comment: I'd suggest getting in contact with the API's creators and asking them to increase their POST limits on the server.

Comment: I created this web api. Are you talking about web config settings ?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to increase the request limits on the server side if possible.

Comment: I changed this but still same
 <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxUrl="1000000" maxQueryString="1000000" />
      </requestFiltering>

Comment: You'll want to change `maxRequestLength`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. When debugging open at Web Api project, project trowing error in windows application project. I started web api without breakpoints and progress finished well but I dont know why..